# How to protect elements that are being edited during project-config/sync?

Tags: updates, frontend-form, projectconfig, project.yaml

Some situations:

1. An editor is editing an entry in the CP while an admin runs `project-config/sync`.
2. A user starts a front end form to create a new entry before `project-config/sync` is run, but submits it after.

What happens to the entry being edited in these situations? Especially if the entry structure gets changed during the sync? I'm afraid of pushing changes that might break the form submission.

If the sync will cause a submission error, what are some ways to work around that? Can I do something like API versioning so the previous structure can be used to submit the edits?